# Clicking pop-up view is Removing Custom Callout from MapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview

MapView didDeselectAnnotationView is getting called when the Callout view is touched.  How do I prevent this?

How do I remove all the custom call-outs pop-ups when didDeselect gets called for MapView without deselecting the view when the pop-up's view is clicked.

--

This is the issue I am running into:
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/custom-annotation-calloutview-disappears-when-its-tapped

Comment: can you show an image for what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This is the issue I am running into: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/custom-annotation-calloutview-disappears-when-its-tapped